# How do I Combine REST and Websocket in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

Where to put these blocks of code for websocket configuration in spring boot REST API? In a REST contoller?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
                .enableSimpleBroker("/chat");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should remain in separate class which is under package that spring scanning, its a configuration class

Answer (score 0):

This is not a controller, it is a configuration file, and it has to go with the configuration files. Along with filter configurations, security, servlet configurations...in short, where are the `@Configuration`, package `*.*.configuration`